# Sharing game data between iPhone / iPad / Mac OSX clients

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, gamekit

I have a game which I am developing for iPhone, iPad and Mac OSX simultaneously. The user needs to be able to pick up the game where he left off on a different device. I'm trying to determine the best approach, both in terms of user-experience and security.

**iCloud** seems the obvious choice. The game data files are unencrypted, though; do I need to worry about a user "hacking" the game by being able to modify an iCloud file? Also, iCloud is separate from GameKit... so wouldn't it be hypothetically possible for a user to log into one user ID (GameKit) but have access to a separate user's data (iCloud)?

**my own server** could be a viable solution. I could use the GameKit user ID as the unique key to represent the user, but I'd need to custom bake security/authentication to prevent spoofing. Also, this obviously has the downside of increased server load. Also, I lose any benefits of iCloud's ability to sync automatically.

Other considerations?

Comment: Amazon hosts web servers which could be the way to go. Look up Amazon AWS. I haven't used them too much but my company uses it to store all kinds of data.

Comment: Using your own server seems like a good option at first, and then you realize that iCloud is managed by IT professionals, has guaranteed up time, have mirrors, built in, automatic, superfast internet, and its free...

Comment: If you want to save the game data on the devices, you also need to encrypt them there, too. Each device can use its own private secret key to perform decryption and encryption on the device. If you receive  encrypted data, you need a particular secrete key to decrypt it. Securely distributing a secret key on several devices may require your own server solution.